# How to convert xml data in Java object using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, xjc

I am new in JAXB conversion. My tag is starting with `<DataSet>` but I need to access data from `<TABLE>` in `<NewDataSet>` tag. Any exact suggestion or Help me if any thing wrong.

Also I have tried lot conversion but not getting exact solution.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns="http://www.test.com">
    <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
        <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="Table">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xs:element name="NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xs:element name="ADDRESS" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                <xs:element name="PIN" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
        <NewDataSet xmlns="">
            <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                <ID>1</ID>
                <NAME>Rajesh</NAME>
                <ADDRESS>Pune</ADDRESS>
                <PIN>412411</PIN>
            </Table>
            <Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                <ID>2</ID>
                <NAME>Ajinkya</NAME>
                <ADDRESS>Mumbai</ADDRESS>
                <PIN>412504</PIN>
            </Table>
        </NewDataSet>
    </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>`

My java code is-

```
File file = new File("/home/raj/Desktop/info.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(NewDataSet.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
NewDataSet dType = (NewDataSet) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

Getting following exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"DataSet"). Expected elements are <{}NewDataSet>
```

Comment: I did not understood what actually you want to say @M.Deinum?
Did you understood my problem, If not then comment here. I will try to explain in detail. I am new to asking question.

Comment: You only dump an XSD here and you haven't even tried (at least that doesn't show from your question) something to process an incoming XML.

Comment: Ok @M.Deinum, you means I should add my java code also what I have tried to process this xml data. Actually it will be large file if I will add all my code, so directly I asked this. May be some one have good suggestions.

Comment: I have generated class by using this command `xjc -d src -p com.test.jaxb.beans test.xsd` from given xsd in my xml.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to help. If you already have exact class Data for the result after converting from xml. I refer you to read this good article from dzon : [Using JAXB for XML With Java](https://dzone.com/articles/using-jaxb-for-xml-with-java)

Here is sample codes for converting from xml to data class :

```
    File file = new File("product.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Product.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    product = (Product) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
    System.out.println(product);
```

If it's custom xml, then I think you must use some html dom, to convert it manually. here is sample using html dom : [Java Read XML – Java DOM Parser Example](https://howtodoinjava.com/xml/read-xml-dom-parser-example/)

Here is sample code of using dom parsing from xml in java :

```
//Get Document Builder
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

//Build Document
Document document = builder.parse(new File("employees.xml"));

//Normalize the XML Structure; It's just too important !!
document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

//Here comes the root node
Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
System.out.println(root.getNodeName());

//Get all employees
NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("employee");
System.out.println("============================");

for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++)
{
 Node node = nList.item(temp);
 System.out.println("");    //Just a separator
 if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
 {
    //Print each employee's detail
    Element eElement = (Element) node;
    System.out.println("Employee id : "    + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
    System.out.println("First Name : "  + eElement.getElementsByTagName("firstName").item(0).getTextContent());
    System.out.println("Last Name : "   + eElement.getElementsByTagName("lastName").item(0).getTextContent());
    System.out.println("Location : "    + eElement.getElementsByTagName("location").item(0).getTextContent());
 }
}
```